# Sort blocks of string on file

Tags: sort

i have lots of spells and relative description (as in rpg) not in alphabetical order.
The code shown is in latex

the first line of each block must contain \index{Spells}

example

```
\medskip\textbf{Aid}\index[Spells]{Aid}\\
\textbf{School}: Heal, Necromancy\\
\textbf{Level}: 2, Uncommon\\
\textbf{Cast Time}: 2 Actions\\
\textbf{Range}: 9 meters\\
\textbf{Components}: V, S, M (a thin strip of white bread)\\
\textbf{Duration}: 1 hour for Magic Competency\\
Your spell increases the toughness and resolve of your allies. Choose up to three creatures within range. For the duration, each target's maximum hit points and current hit points increase by 5.\\
\textbf{For each magical critical success rolled} in the Magic Test the target's hit points are increased by an additional 5 points

\medskip\textbf{Halucination of Death}\index[Spells]{Halucination of Death}\\
\textbf{School}: Illusion\\
\textbf{Level}: 4, Uncommon\\
\textbf{Cast Time}: 2 Actions\\
\textbf{Range}: 36 meters\\
\textbf{Components}: V, S\\
\textbf{Duration}: Instant\\
You draw upon the nightmares of a creature within range and that you can see, and create an illusory manifestation of its deepest fears, visible only to that creature. The target must make a Will save. \\
On a failed save, the target is frightened for 1 minute and takes 4d10 damage. \\
\textbf{For each magical critical success rolled} in the Magic Test the damage increases by 1d10

\medskip\textbf{Alarm}\index[Spells]{Alarm}\\
\textbf{School}: Abjuration\\
\textbf{Level}: 1, Common\\
\textbf{Cast Time}: 1 minute\\
\textbf{Range}: 9 meters\\
\textbf{Components}: V, S, M (a bell)\\
\textbf{Duration}: 8 hours\\
Set up an alarm against unwanted intrusions. Choose a door, window, or area within range that is no larger than a 6 meters cube. Until the spell ends, you will be warned by an alarm whenever a creature of Tiny size or larger comes into contact with or enters the protected area.....
```

and so on... i need to sort by block ordering by name in Index value (as \index[Spells]{Alarm} )
in this case the order would be

````
\medskip\textbf{Aid}\index[Spells]{Aid}..and relative text..\\
\medskip\textbf{Alarm}\index[Spells]{Alarm}....and relative text...\\
\medskip\textbf{Halucination of Death}... and relative text....\\```


how to do on linux ?

thanks

BHH
````

Answer (score 0):

With GNU awk, capturing the spell name in a regular expression match, and using it as an array index, then sorting the array on its index:

```
gawk '
  BEGIN {
    RS=""
    FS="\n"
  }
  match($1,/\\index\[Spells\]\{([^}]*)\}/,m) {
    spells[m[1]] = $0
  }
  END {
    PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_str_asc"
    ORS="\n\n"
    for(i in spells) print spells[i]
  }
' example.tex
```

Comment: thanks! but not fully working, text within empty lines is cutted out

example :

\textbf{School}: Air, Water, Earth, Fire\\
\textbf{Level}: 4, Uncommon\\
\textbf{Cast Time}: 1 minute\\
\textbf{Range}: 27 meters\\
\textbf{Components}: V, S\\
\textbf{Duration}: 1 hour\\
You summon elementals that will appear in unoccupied spaces ...

- An elemental of challenge rating 2 or lower\\

\medskip
A summoned elemental disappears ....```

also spells with "-" in index aren't imported

```\medskip\textbf{Prestidigitation}\index{Cantrip - Prestidigitation}\\
```